# Ways to express "Thank you" in English

Tags: expressions, american-english

I am wondering how many expressions in English can express "Thank you" (I am just running out of them)

1. Thank you (very much) or Thanks.
2. Many thanks!
3. I appreciate it indeed!
4. Thanks a million!
5. I can't say enough thanks to you

May I know more?

Comment: Another way is: visit my site and click on my PayPal donation buttons. :)

Comment: Cheers! Ta! Wonderful! (In the sense of *That help you provided was wonderful*.) It's also common to borrow French and Spanish words, for some reason.

Comment: "Don't mention it" which can also be said simply as "No worries". Other options are "You have my gratitude" or "I am grateful" or *very* informally, "You're a life-saver!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

"I am so grateful."
"I am eternally grateful."
"You'll never know how grateful I am."
"You have my gratitude"
"Wow! That really helped!"
I'm sure there are many others. 
I know the last one does not literally give thanks, but I think that it, and other phrases like it, imply(ies) gratitude.

Answer (score 2):

"Much obliged" can be used. An old way of saying thank you.

Comment: For some reason this reminded me of "Ta muchly".